# Can one eat meat on Mot'za'ei 9 Av if it is a se'udah for Brit or Pidyon Haben?

Tags: halacha, brit-milah, meat, nine-days, pidyon-haben

Many halachic opinions state that the prohibition of not eating meat during the 9 Days extends until the middle of the 10th of Av. Does this prohibition apply if you are making a se'udah for a Brit or Pidyon Haben (i.e. - the Brit or Pidyon was on 9 Av, but the se'udah was postponed.)

Answer (score 1):

[Per Chabad.org it is permitted](http://www.chabad.org.il/Articles/Article.asp?ArticleID=1188&CategoryID=736)

> כשעושים סעודת ברית מילה או פדיון הבן במוצאי תשעה-באב, מותר להזמין כמה
>   אנשים שרוצים, וכולם מותרים אז בבשר ויין